# Cannot upgrade octave on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, homebrew, octave

I have tried updating GNU Octave through homebrew. However, I receive the following errors:

```
adamg:~ adamg$ brew install octave
==> Installing octave from homebrew/science
Error: You must `brew link gmp lua` before homebrew/science/octave can be installed
adamg:~ adamg$ brew link gmp lua
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a... 
Error: Could not symlink include/gmpxx.h
Target /usr/local/include/gmpxx.h
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/include/gmpxx.h'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite gmp

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run gmp
adamg:~ adamg$ rm '/usr/local/include/gmpxx.h'
adamg:~ adamg$ brew link gmp lua
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a... 
Error: Could not symlink share/info/gmp.info
Target /usr/local/share/info/gmp.info
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/share/info/gmp.info'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite gmp

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run gmp
```

I could use octave before, but it was loading version 3.8.1. Now when I try to load it, I receive the following error

```
adamg:~ adamg$ octave
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libhdf5.9.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/octave/3.8.1_1/bin/octave-cli-3.8.1
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Any insight into what went wrong? I am running OSX 10.11.5.

Comment: How did /usr/local/include/gmpxx.h get there as it is not a symbolic link it must be part off something installed not through homebrew

Comment: I'm not sure what it is. What should I do about that?